# Closing a file descriptor, >&- vs <&-

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

In the bash tutorial I am reading, it says that if you open a file descriptor for reading, i.e.

```
exec 3< echolist
```

Then you must close it like this,

```
exec 3<&-
```

However, if you open a file descriptor for writing, it must be closed like this:

```
exec 3>&-
```

Yet when I look on the internet, I see people opening files and then closing them with this:

```
exec 3>&-
```

**NOTE:** when, according to the tutorial, they should be using `exec 3<&1`.

So my question is, can all file descriptors be closed via `exec n>&-` where n is the file descriptor number? Regardless if it was opened for reading, writing, or both?

Comment: The only difference between `>&-` and `<&-` is the default fd when not specified (`>&-` is `1>&-` while `<&-` is `0<&-`). Same for `x>&y` which is the same as `x<&y` except when `x` is not provided.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can close file descriptor using both `<&-` and `>&-`, `bash` will parse two syntax as the same.

From file [y.tab.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/y.tab.c) in `bash` source code:

```
5385   /* Hack <&- (close stdin) case.  Also <&N- (dup and close). */                
5386   if MBTEST(character == '-' && (last_read_token == LESS_AND || last_read_token == GREATER_AND))
5387     return (character);
```

Comment: This can be used on `<>` file descriptors too.

Comment: No that's not possible, but as in `3>&-` or `3<&-` appears to close the descriptor.

Comment: `<>` is a read/write file descriptor, allowing one to read and write to the descriptor.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I know! But what do you mean `This can be used on <> file descriptors too`?

Comment: That closing `<>` can be done via the same ways.

Comment: I can't get what you mean. Please give an example./

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Run `exec 3<>&-`, and you'll get an error: **-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'**. Bash 4.2 here.

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant. Just that a a read write file descriptor can be closed using 3>&- and 3<&- as well.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I can see, `exec 3>&-` and `exec 3<&-` are the same and can be used on any file descriptor, regardless of how it was opened. According to sections 2.7.6 and 2.7.5 of the POSIX definition of the [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07):

> 2.7.5 Duplicating an Input File Descriptor
>
> The redirection operator:
>
> [n]<&word
>
> [...SNIP...]
>
> If word evaluates to '-', file descriptor n, or standard input if n is
>   not specified, shall be closed. Attempts to close a file descriptor
>   that is not open shall not constitute an error. If word evaluates to
>   something else, the behavior is unspecified.
>
> 2.7.6 Duplicating an Output File Descriptor
>
> The redirection operator:
>
> [n]>&word
>
> [...SNIP...]
>
> If word evaluates to '-', file descriptor n, or standard output if n
>   is not specified, is closed. Attempts to close a file descriptor that
>   is not open shall not constitute an error. If word evaluates to
>   something else, the behavior is unspecified.

Note that neither specifies anything about how file descriptor n was opened originally.  This is in line with the fact that [close(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) doesn't care about how you opened the file.

A quick strace of the following:

```
exec 3< /etc/passwd
exec 4> foo
exec 3<&-
exec 4<&-
```

versus this:

```
exec 3< /etc/passwd
exec 4> foo
exec 3<&-
exec 4>&-
```

shows that in both cases, Bash does exactly the same thing.

**Two Mildly Interesting Facts**

- The [bash man page section on duplicating file descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors) does not mention that `[n]>&-` closes file descriptors.
- In the Bash code for handling redirects (redir.c) you can find this:

  ```
  738      /* XXX - what to do with [N]<&$w- where w is unset or null?  ksh93
  739               closes N. */
  ```

Comment: The bash man page does mentioned closing, quoting your link: _If word evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n is closed._

Comment: @studog Thanks for checking the source!  I think what happened here is I was looking at a local manpage for Bash 3, and then linked to the online documentation, which was for Bash 4.  In the old Bash 3 documentation, the phrase about closing was omitted from the description of `[N]>&WORD`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/bashref.info?id=f1be666c#n1857

Answer (score 9):

An example for cuonglm's understanding of closing a '<>' FD.

This is quoted from the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

```
[j]<>filename
  #  Open file "filename" for reading and writing,
  #+ and assign file descriptor "j" to it.
  #  If "filename" does not exist, create it.
  #  If file descriptor "j" is not specified, default to fd 0, stdin.
  #
  #  An application of this is writing at a specified place in a file. 
  echo 1234567890 > File    # Write string to "File".
  exec 3<> File             # Open "File" and assign fd 3 to it.
  read -n 4 <&3             # Read only 4 characters.
  echo -n . >&3             # Write a decimal point there.
  exec 3>&-                 # Close fd 3.
  cat File                  # ==> 1234.67890
  #  Random access, by golly.
```