# How to terminate a TCP connection established by bash itself?

Tags: bash, pipe, tcp, file-descriptors

I have used `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.0.101/6435` to establish a TCP connection with 192.168.0.101:6435. And I have received as well as sent a few messages with the `pipe` command.

Now, I want to terminate the TCP connection. But, with `ss -anpet` I can see that bash itself holds this connection, without forking a child process.

I tried to send signal 9 and 15 to the bash process, but as you know, bash cannot kill itself.

So, can I terminate the TCP connection I have established without terminating the pts I am using (neither killing it by root nor sending Ctrl+D)?

Comment: Could you get another shell & kill `bash` with that shell?

Comment: `bash` certainly *can* kill itself - though that's not actually what you want to do here!

Comment: @TJM to make this fascinating question more useful to others, could you please elaborate on the `pipe` command you're using and which I can't find on my system?  Which package does `pipe` comes from? What (example) parameters can you pass to it to send/receive data over the `/dev/tcp/...` connection?  Thanks.

Comment: @arielf Typically, I am a beginner of Computer Science, and I found this kind of usage from a bash shell script called sedbot, you can find it on Github. Yes, I cannot find any files in `/dev/tcp`, even cannot find `/dev/tcp` itself. But, it seems a special usage that you can send/receive data with `pipe` and this kind of files. It is said that use `/dev/tcp/ip/port` for tcp connections, and `/dev/udp/ip/port` for udp packages. For my English is not very good, I don not know how to explain it properly. Please feel free to edit the question and post an answer.

Comment: @TJM thanks. The question was about the `pipe` command that you mention.  I looked at `https://github.com/clsr/sedbot/blob/master/sedbot.bash`.  There's no `pipe` command there.  It defines two functions: `readmsg` and `sendmsg` to read/write from/to the connection respectively. `readmsg` uses `IFS= read -r -u 3 -t "$READ_TIMEOUT" line` to read from file-descriptor 3 into the variable `line`, and `sendmsg` uses `echo "$(date +%s.%N) >>> $line" >&4` to write into file descriptor 4.  Anyway, this clarifies the full method. The "`pipe` command" mention still remains a mystery to readers.

Comment: @arielf Take care of Line 30

Comment: @TJM line #30 is well understood (redirects to & from the tcp connection). `pipe` (in your question) isn't.

Comment: @arielf It seems that if a pipe is assigned to a subpath of `/dev/tcp` or `/dev/udp` the bash will create a socket and use these tcp/udp. And when the assigned pipe is released, the socket will be stoped. That's why `pipe` is in the question tag. Thank you for your recommending :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That command opened the connection on file descriptor 3. So to close the connection, you need to close file descriptor 3.
To do so:

```
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Will this do a proper `shutdown(3)` call, or just `close(2)` the file descriptor?

Comment: Does a `close`, but `shutdown` is no more proper than close. `shutdown`'s only real use is when you only want to close one side of a duplex socket.

Comment: [A `shutdown` sends a FIN, while a `close` sends a RST.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23483487/1340389)  These are materially different things.

Comment: @Kevin RST is caused by closing the socket without reading all the data from it first. If you read to the end of the data and then do a close, the close will send a FIN.

Comment: @kasperd: In the UNIX socket API, the only way to know whether there is data pending is to either try to read from a nonblocking socket, or call something like `select()`, and I don't believe bash provides for either option.

Comment: @Patrick If you want to signal to the other end of the connection that you have no more data to send, then a `shutdown` call is the way to do it.

Comment: @Kevin Both of those approaches would be flawed anyway. If you want to avoid sending a RST, you have to read all the data from the socket, which may include data the other end has not written to the socket yet. Ultimately it depends on the protocol you are speaking how exactly to signal the end of data. A protocol could use FIN to signal the end of the data, but a FIN could happen for other reasons such as if the sending process got killed.

Comment: @kasperd: ...which is why I'm so confused by your suggestion to "read to the end of the data and then do a close" - there is no general way to do that!  The proper way to end a TCP session is by calling `shutdown`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41087/discussion-between-kasperd-and-kevin).

Comment: @Patrick: Or `exec 3>&-` http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131833/38906