# What is this script doing?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, read, exec

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 123456789 > out.txt
exec 3<> out.txt
read -n 4 <&3
echo -n 5 >&3
exec 3>&-
```

Was asked the content of out.txt at the end of script, in an interview written exam. I did run the script afterwords and it gave me `123456789`. Yet I have no idea what is going on in the script, especially the parts with the exec statements. I looked up the manpage and google search results for `exec` and could not find anything on the `3<>` bit. Could somebody, well versed in shell scripting, explain what is going on here?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265106/332764).

Comment: wow, this was ripped off line for line. thanks @Freddy for pointing me to the relevant resource

Comment: Add an `echo "$REPLY"` anywhere after the line with the `read` command and run it. you should `1234` which is what the `-n4`  does

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo 123456789 > out.txt` writes the string `123456789` in `out.txt` file.

The `exec 3<>out.txt` construct opens the file `out.txt` for reading `<` and writing `>` and attaches it to file descriptor #3.

`read -n 4 <&3` reads 4 characters.

`echo -n 5 >&3` writes 5 (replacing 5 by 5).

`exec 3>&-` closes file descriptor #3.

Resulting in

```
cat out.txt
123456789
```

Section about `exec`int [`bash(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) states that:

> **`exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`** If `command` is specified, it replaces the shell. [...] *If `command` is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell [...].*